# Seeking concise specifications for the interface (classes and functions) that a JDBC driver must implement

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I am being asked to write a JDBC driver that wraps a non-SQL 3rd-party data API.

In order to understand what interface (classes and functions) my custom JDBC driver must implement, I have done the following:

- Attempted to locate information for JDBC driver *developers* (not users) from [Oracle's JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/index.html), but the documentation does not make clear where the JDBC driver developer specifications are located - it is focused on *users* of JDBC (as far as I can see)
- Looked in the /java/sql directory of the jdk1.7.0_09 installation's source code.  However, of the dozens of source code files in this directory, it is not clear which actually represent the required interfaces that must be implemented
- Found the following sample JDBC driver: [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/), and downloaded the source code for this project for use as sample code; however, it is not clear which files implement required JDBC driver functionality, and which are specific to this JDBC driver
- Found the following sample JDBC driver: [JDBC File Driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbcfiledriver/), and attempted to download the source code for this project for use as sample code; however, only .class files seemed available

Is there a concise set of specifications available that describes the interface (classes and functions) that a minimal and/or recommended JDBC driver must implement?

Comment: There is the official multiple documentation on the several JDBC levels. That certainly is not *concise*, though normative. Maybe you can find unit tests. Otherwise make them. Simply go for the interfaces. I would make two implementations, one delegating to MySQL.

Comment: There is a testsuite for JDBC, but you will need to go through a bureaucratic process to get access, and as a commercial entity you will also need to pay a yearly fee for the privilege to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the JDBC specification. It is available on the JCP site as [JSR221](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html).
Follow the link and click under the paragraph 'If you intend to build an implementation of the specification...'. It will bring you to the download page for implementors.

Comment: I am sorry, but if you need to implement the specification, there's no  simple route. You need to implement a great bunch of functionalities so, if CsvJdbc seems complex so will the specification.

Comment: pp. 31-35 are exactly what I'm looking for.  I don't care whether the specifications are simple or complex, just so long as I know what they are and therefore understand what I need to implement to create the JDBC driver.

Comment: It is better to take the JDBC 4.1 specification as it is more recent: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index.html

Comment: JDBC 4.2 here: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html